# Bloc pattern update ui with listener or stream

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

in my implementation `Bloc` pattern i can get some data from server like with `name` and `email`, i can show this data with separated widget in layout such as show name with `Text`, as i have some widget in layout such as 
`Text('Hi $_username')`
before getting data from server i want to try update this variable after getting data from server

for example:

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  final LoginListingBloc loginListingBloc;

  Login({this.loginListingBloc});

  State<Login> createState() {
    return _Login(loginListingBloc: loginListingBloc);
  }
}

class _Login extends State<Login> {
  var _userPageName='';
  _Login({this.loginListingBloc});

  final LoginListingBloc loginListingBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  ...child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "welcome $_userPageName",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                              ...
                            ],
                          )),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ...
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    loginListingBloc.dispatch(LoginEvent(loginInfoModel: testLogin));
                                  },
                                  iconSize: 40.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      LoginListing()
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginListing extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(
        bloc: BlocProvider.of<LoginListingBloc>(context),
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoginUninitializedState) {
            return Message(
              message: 'login is not available',
            );
          } else if (state is LoginFetchingState) {
            return Expanded(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (state is LoginErrorState) {
            return Message(message: 'Error');
          } else {
            final stateAsLoginFetchedState = state as LoginFetchedState;
            final loginInfo = stateAsLoginFetchedState.userInfo;
            return buildShowLoginInfoItems(loginInfo);
          }
        });
  }

  Widget buildShowLoginInfoItems(UserInfo userInfo) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(userInfo.name),
    );
  }
}
```

in that how can i update `$_userPageName` after click on `IconButton`?

my `LoginListingBloc` implemented class:

```
class LoginListingBloc extends Bloc<LoginListingEvent, LoginListingStates> {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;

  LoginListingBloc({this.loginRepository});

  @override
  LoginListingStates get initialState => LoginUninitializedState();

  @override
  Stream<LoginListingStates> mapEventToState(
      LoginListingStates currentState, LoginListingEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginEvent) {
      yield LoginFetchingState();
      try {
        final loginInfo = await loginRepository.fetchLoginToPage(
            event.loginInfoModel.username, event.loginInfoModel.password);
        yield LoginFetchedState(userInfo: loginInfo);
      } catch (_) {
        yield LoginErrorState();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making use of your `BlocBuilder`?

Comment: @nonybrighto yes, but i can't make it

Comment: Aw! Missed this. Have u been able to solve your problem?

Comment: @nonybrighto yes, where is your question link it for me maybe i can help you

Comment: Nope. Wanted to solve make it work.